# Unable to export physical Linux system to VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clonezilla, vdi

I would like to save my Linux system (including **packages, files, and configuration**) and export it to another laptop in the form of a virtual machine with VirtualBox.

I have been able to create a file of the correct format (**.vdi**) with these commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/media/HDD/disk.img
VBoxManage convertdd disk.img disk.vdi --format VDI
```

I was also able to achieve this through this line:

```
sudo dd if=DRIVE | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin FILENAME.vdi BYTES
```

However, when I open the generated VDI file as an existing hard disk in VirtualBox, the same error is displayed each time I try to boot: `no bootable medium found.`

I also tried another solution with the CloneZilla tool running on a live USB key; I was able to generate an image of my system and to store it on an external hard drive.

That image is not recognized when I proceed to the restoration on my virtual machine. The USB device containing the image does not appear inside the list of the partitions.

Here my /dev/sdb output:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 24.0 GB, 24015495168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2919 cylinders, total 46905264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7ef857ad

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1    46905263    23452631+  ee  GPT
```

And UUID here [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGsN6.png) matches with [/etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGJke.png) in /dev/sdb1.

Comment: what distro does the linux system run?

Comment: Just Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Are you sure the original system boots from /dev/sdb? Can you describe the full boot chain that leaves the Linux system running?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure : /dev/sdb represents my 24 GB SDD disk with contains my entire linux system, /dev/sda is actually used as dual booting for windows system.

Comment: So the system boot starts in sda? If so, how does it boot the Linux system in sdb?

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: I added my /dev/sdb output

Comment: Pls see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to install (or re-install, or repair) GRUB2 on your image is to use another VM running Linux. The alternative, [the answer by toh](https://superuser.com/questions/130955/how-to-install-grub-into-an-img-file), is rather complicated. If you boot a Linux VM, having plugged into it also your new disk image (besides the VM's own disk), it will be treated not as a file but as a real disk, bypassing the need for the device mapper (see link above).

So, boot another Linux VM, mount your new vdi disk,

```
       mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

and chroot into it:

```
   mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount -o bind /sys  /mnt/sys
   mount -o bind /dev  /mnt/dev
   cd /mnt; chroot .
```

Now you can install grub as follows

```
   grub-install /dev/sdb
   update-grub /dev/sdb
```

then leave the `chroot` environment (by means of `exit' or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and

```
  umount /mnt/dev
  umount /mnt/proc
  umount /mnt/sys
  umount /mnt
```

Your new vdi disk is now bootable, and can be used as **the** disk of a new Linux VM.